# Bulk API v2.0 Failed records are confused

Tags: data-loader, bulk-api, upsert

I'm developing code in java for upload data to Salesforce. All did fine but I've a problem with failed records with bulk API 2.0 with upsert action

I have the next file csv for upload data for Account:

```
Name, Date_i__c,description,unique_id__c
Account1,2018-02-01,description1,1
Account2,2018-02-01,description2,2
Account3,2018-02-01,description3,3
Account4,2018-X2-01,description4,4
```

I know that the Account4 is wrong because the format for date is incorrect.

When I check the results:

```
Ok --> successfulResults (3 records)
Failed --> failedResults (1 record)
```

In successfulResults is fine, I know that 3 records now are in salesforce but when I check the failed results, is like this:

```
sf_id,sf_error,Name,Date_i__c,description,unique_id__c
"","description of error", "","","",""
```

So, I don't know which record is failed!
I wait something like this:

```
sf_id,sf_error,Name,Date_i__c,description,unique_id__c
"","description of error", "Account4","2018-X2-01","description4","4"
```

In this example maybe is easy because only I have 3 records but if I will have 10,000 records?

I've try many ways to know which are the records failed but I don't have some idea

Comment: In addition to the successful results file, there should be a failed results file (can't recall what it would be called at the moment). Check your results directory - both will be generated on every bulk job.

Comment: I know that Bulk Api generates 3 paths of results, successful, failed, and unprocessed, so when I check the failed records only show the error but not the record failed information. In unprocessed is empty and It's correct

Answer (score -1):

Check this: Bulk API 2.0 returns failed and success results with empty field values
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000349496&type=1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/181672)